# running Docker compose build --no-cache

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile, alpine-linux

I want to run Geonode on Ubuntu VM and when I run the command

```bash
docker-compose build --no-cache
```

following [this guide](https://docs.geonode.org/en/4.1.x/install/advanced/core/index.html?ssp=1&setlang=en&cc=IT&safesearch=moderate#databases-and-permissions) I face the error below and I don't know how I can solve it:

```
Dockerfile:3
1 | FROM nginx:1-alpine
2 |
3 | >>> RUN apk add --no-cache openssl inotify-tools
4 |
5 | WORKDIR /etc/nginx/
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apk add --no-cache openssl inotify-tools" did not complete successfully: exit code: 2
ERROR: Service 'geonode' failed to build : Build failed
```